# Is there a simple way to make a whole DOM subtree readonly with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, readonly

I'm having a few `input`s and all of them should become `readonly` when some property changes (e.g., the shopping cart gets checked out).

I sort of could add `ng-readonly=cart.checkedOut` to each such input, which is boring, prone to forgetting, and complicated by the fact that there are partials which don't have any access to `cart`.

So I'm thinking about modifying `input` (and `textarea` and `select`, which are just misnamed inputs), so that it looks in its DOM ancestors for class `readonly` and possibly makes itself readonly. My problem is the interaction with `ng-readonly` which may make the `input` readonly for a different reason. It looks like I'd have to modify `ng-readonly`, but AFAIK there's no way to modify existing directives, only add another behavior to the same name.

Somehow, I'm feeling lost; I'm sure there's a simple solution, but everything gets complicated as I dive into. Showing me the proper direction would suffice. Or maybe a different solution for the original problem.

Comment: use a directive that can check any scope conditions and set the property accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the `readonly` attribute is ignored for several form input elements.

As such, `ng-readonly` might not work as you'd expect for some components (i.e. it will not prevent user interaction from editing a value).

That said, one way to go about your problem would be to craft a directive that watches the checked out state and dynamically adds or strips appropriate input element attributes that make them appear locked for editing.

Like I mentioned above, the attributes you'd need to be concerned with depends on the types of elements you use. For those in which `readonly` does not apply, like `select`, you can instead opt to use `disable`. However, disabled elements can't be submitted, which is why the `hidden` input type is often used to supplement `select` elements. It's seems undesirable in your case too, as you wish to not touch your DOM.

To still use `disable` and work around the latter problem, on submission of your form, you can craft another directive to strip all `disabled` attributes from input elements that have them, ensuring all input data gets submitted.

Here's a basic demonstration on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yiduze/) of how to dynamically manage input element attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I cooked up, which extends on the `input`, `select` and `textarea` directives.

Using `$provide.decorator` in our config block of our application, we can augment these directives behaviour without touching their internal implementation.

What I suggest you do, is to set up a listener for an event that you broadcast off of your containing `$scope`. Attach a callback, that checks for the `nodeName` of the current input directive - and toggle user input off (using `readOnly` or `disabled`).

Something along these lines:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {

  var directives = [
    'input',
    'select',
    'textarea'
  ];

  var eventName = '__disableInputs';

  angular.forEach(directives, function (directive) {

    $provide.decorator(directive + 'Directive', function ($delegate, $controller) {

      // Decorating directives returns an array. Select the first index.
      var directive = $delegate[0];

      // If a controller is tied to the directive, store a reference to it.
      if (directive.controller) {
        var origCtrl = directive.controller;
      }

      // Define a new controller on the directive.
      directive.controller = function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        if (origCtrl) {
          // Extend this new controller with the old behaviour of the 
          // original controller.
          angular.extend(this, $controller(origCtrl, { 
            $scope: $scope,
            $element: $element,
            $attrs: $attrs
          }));
        }

        // Add an event listener to the directive controller.
        var unlisten = $scope.$on(eventName, function () {
          if ($element[0].nodeName === 'SELECT') {
            $element[0].disabled = true;
          } else {
            $element[0].readOnly = true;
          }
        });

        $scope.$on('$destroy', unlisten);
      };

      // Return the original (augmented) directive.
      return $delegate;      
    });
  });
});
```

Then, we can simply trigger the behaviour from a controller (or some other place):

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('__disableInput', {});
  }, 5000);

});
```

Now, every `input`, `select`, and `textarea` currently residing in the broadcasting
scope should have their respetive callback applied and not be editable through regular
user means anymore.

One could potentially trigger this off of $rootScope aswell - but; when working with built in `ng` directives, 
I'd say it's a good practice to add our own custom flag that decides whether or not a directive listens for the
eventName defined in our config block (`__disableInput`) or not.

If we want to add this custom flag, 
we should change our new `directive.controller` function to look like this:

```
if (origCtrl) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller(origCtrl, { 
    $scope: $scope,
    $element: $element,
    $attrs: $attrs
  }));  
}

// Only add our eventlistener if canBeDisabled is set.
if ($attrs.canBeDisabled !== undefined) {

  var unlisten = $scope.$on(eventName, function (e, data) {
    if ($element[0].nodeName === 'SELECT') {
      $element[0].disabled = true;
    } else {
      $element[0].readOnly = true;
    }
  });

  $scope.$on('$destroy', unlisten);
}
```

Then in our view we'd do:

```
<input ng-model="someModel.property" can-be-disabled type="text">
```

Now, this is a crude example and there may be some gotchas that I have not explored yet.
But I do think it's a step in the right direction if you want to have a *simple* way
of extending `ng` directives without necessarily touching their internals and/or creating
new directives.

One thing I haven't done is to define the `eventName` as an `app.value` (or `app.constant`), 
that way we wouldn't have to define the eventName in the config block or worry about misspellings
when setting up a broadcaster of this event. We'd simply inject the value into our context
and use it as the name for the event.

Here's a JSBin for you: http://jsbin.com/xipokuyi/5/edit

And a link to an article exploring this type of approach more in-depth: 
http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr;

An auxiliary service is used as communication mechanism between directive and controllers. The services registers & unregisters elements (in the directive link function) and enables & disables all registered elements by a function call (in the controller).

### Solution 1 -- readonly elements in any location

[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/mU8nRI2KW2a9BOIeIuBO?p=preview) is a seed<sup>1</sup> of my solution, in which elements may be located anywhere in the DOM tree.

#### auxiliary service

```
app.factory("demoReadonlyState", function(){

  var elements = [];
  var state = false;

  return {
    enable : function(){
      state = false;
      for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++){
        elements[i].removeAttribute('readonly');
      }
    },
    disable : function(){
      state = true;
      for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++){
        elements[i].setAttribute('readonly', "True");
      }
    },
    addElement : function(domEl) { 
      elements.push(domEl);
      if(state){
        domEl.setAttribute('readonly', state);
      }
      else {
        domEl.removeAttribute('readonly');
      }
      console.log("add -- # elements: ", elements.length);
    },
    removeElement : function(el) {
      var index = elements.indexOf(el);
      if (index > -1) {
        elements.splice(index, 1);
      }
      console.log("remove -- # elements: ", elements.length);
    }
  }
})
```

#### directive

```
app.directive("demoReadonly", function(demoReadonlyState){

  return {
    link : function(scope, element){
      console.log(demoReadonlyState);
      demoReadonlyState.addElement(element[0]);
      element.on('$destroy', function(){
        demoReadonlyState.removeElement(element);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

#### usage

In `JS`:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, demoReadonlyState){
  $scope.roState = demoReadonlyState;
  $scope.roState.enable();
  //$scope.roState.disable();
});
```

In `HTML`:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input demo-readonly />
    <input />
    <input demo-readonly />
    <input />
    <input demo-readonly />
    <input />

    <div>
      <button ng-click="roState.enable()">enable</button>
      <button ng-click="roState.disable()">disable</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button ng-click="arr.push([])">add element</button>
      <button ng-click="arr.length && arr.splice(0,1)">remove element</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="x in arr">
      <input demo-readonly/>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> By seed I mean, that it is not configurable. In normal solution the directive could be passed a string (`demo-readonly="type_X"`), that specifies a group of elements that should be `enabled/disabled` together, leaving all other groups intact.

### Solution 2 -- readonly elements in DOM subtree

[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/CRzmM7VRZLGZ6FAt02Ut?p=preview) is a bit different approach that handles a subtree with a single directive. It can handle multiple subtrees independent from each other. In this form it would not work with dynamic `ng-repeat` well<sup>2</sup>, but more robust mechanism could be easily implemented (though it would require using additional directive).

#### auxiliary service

```
app.factory("demoReadonlyState", function(){

  var elements = {};

  return {
    enable : function(type){
      element = elements[type];
      var inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input');
      for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++){
        inputs[i].removeAttribute('readonly');
      }
    },
    disable : function(type){
      element = elements[type];
      var inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input');
      for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++){
        inputs[i].setAttribute('readonly', "True");
      }
    },
    addElement : function(type, domEl) { 
      elements[type] = domEl;
    },
    removeElement : function(type) {
      delete elements[type];
    }
  }
})
```

#### directive

```
app.directive("demoReadonly", function(demoReadonlyState){

  return {
    scope : {
      type : "@demoReadonly"
    },
    link : function(scope, element){
      demoReadonlyState.addElement(scope.type, element[0]);
      element.on('$destroy', function(){
        demoReadonlyState.removeElement(scope.type);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

#### usage

In `JS`:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, demoReadonlyState){
  $scope.roState = demoReadonlyState;
  $scope.roState.enable('XXX');
  //$scope.roState.disable('XXX');
});
```

In `HTML`:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <button ng-click="roState.enable('XXX')">enable</button>
      <button ng-click="roState.disable('XXX')">disable</button>
    </div>


    <div demo-readonly="XXX">
      <input/>
      <input/>
      <div>
        <input/>
        <input/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Basically using dynamic `ng-repeat` requires a manual call to `enable/disable` after each update of the collection.